# Zhiyun Weebill Lab with Tokina 11-20mm?

Tags: lens, dslr, tokina

Have anyone used the Zhiyun Weebill Lab gimbal with a crop sensor DSLR and the Tokina 11-20mm lens? Would it balance without a problem? Would it balance with an ND filter screwed on?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic - though I think a broader, *how do I know my gimbal will work* type question would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Spec says it holds 3kg. Put your camera+lens+ND filter on your kitchen scale and check. My EOS70D and my heaviest lens (a 120-400mm) total 2.5kg, so your is likely well below this. The gimbal seems to come with a sliding plate, so the longitudinal position of the CG shouldn't be an issue either.